# Formulario de registro ajax y php

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, pdo

Cordial saludo.

Tengo una duda, tengo una aplicación que estoy desarrollando en PHP con MySQLy JavaScript pero en el momento de realizar una registro a la base de datos a través de JavaScript el mensaje enviado es de error cuando reviso en el registro de la base de datos me muestra que realizado la inserción a la base de datos.

**Este es el código Javascript:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#btnRegistrar').click(function(){

    datos=$('#frmDocentes').serialize();

    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"../../Docente/Controller/AddController.php",
        data:datos,
        success:function(r){
            if(r==1){
                $('frmDocentes')[0].reset();
                alertify.success('Se ha Registrado Nuevo Docente :)');
            }else{
                alertify.error('Fallo al Registrar Nuevo Docente :(');
            }
        }
    });
    return false;
  });   
});
```

**Este es el código en el modelo:**

```
 public function add($nombre , $apellido ,$correo ,$telefono ,$especialidad){
    $statement = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO docentes(Nombre , Apellido ,Correo ,Telefono ,Especialidad) VALUES (:nombre , :apellido , :correo, :telefono, :especialidad)");
    $statement->bindParam(':nombre',$nombre);
    $statement->bindParam(':apellido',$apellido);
    $statement->bindParam(':telefono',$correo);
    $statement->bindParam(':correo',$telefono);
    $statement->bindParam(':especialidad',$especialidad);
    if($statement->execute()){
        header('Location:../View/index.php');
    }else{
        header('Location:../View/add.php');    
    }
  }
```

Cuando realizo la consulta me manda un **alertify.error** siendo que la consulta realizada esta bien y reviso en la base de datos y efectivamente realizo el registro.

**Edit:** (adjunto)

**AddController.php**

```
<?php 
    require_once('../Model/ModelDocente.php'); 

    if($_POST) { 
        $ModeloDocente = new Docente(); 

        $Nombre =$_POST['nombre']; 
        $Apellido =$_POST['apellido']; 
        $Correo = $_POST['correo']; 
        $Telefono = $_POST['telefono']; 
        $Especialidad = $_POST['especialidad']; 
        $ModeloDocente->add($Nombre,$Apellido,$Correo,$Telefono,$Especialidad); 
    } else { 
        header('Location:../../Login.php'); 
    } 
?>
```

Comment: y "r" en que momento lo retornas con valor 1 si todo se hizo correctamente?

Comment: En tu código solo veo que rediriges con *header* , pero donde devuelves 1 o 0? Sube el código de **AddController.php** para ayudar mejor.

Comment: ¿y porque intentas enviar, desde el PHP, un header en una petición ajax?

Comment: '<?php
   require_once('../Model/ModelDocente.php');
   if($_POST){
    $ModeloDocente = new Docente();
    $Nombre =$_POST['nombre'];
    $Apellido =$_POST['apellido'];
    $Correo = $_POST['correo'];
    $Telefono = $_POST['telefono'];
    $Especialidad = $_POST['especialidad'];
    $ModeloDocente->add($Nombre,$Apellido,$Correo,$Telefono,$Especialidad);
   }else{
      header('Location:../../Login.php');
   }
?>'

Comment: este seria el codigo del controlador , esta es mi primera aplicacion ya que estoy aprendiendo programacion en php

Comment: Sería mejor que lo añades a tu preguntar, puedes darle a editar. Como te he dicho para que devolver *header()* eso no está bien, en tu función, porque no retornas si se registró el usuario un ```return 1;``` y si es falso un ```return 0;``` que es lo que está esperando de retorno tu AJAX para tomar una acción u otra.

Answer (score 1):

Para que tu AJAX te devuelva una respuesta, desde PHP deberías devolver **1** o **0** como respuesta, ya que aquí `if(r==1){}` es lo que solicitas como respuesta, entonces usando los `header('location: pagina.php')`, siempre te lo va ignorar.

Para solucionarlo, podrías simplemente devolver un `return 1;` si se inserto correcto o `return 0;` en caso contrario, esto desde tu función `add()`.

**Posible ejemplo:**

*AddController.php*

```
require_once('../Model/ModelDocente.php'); 

if(isset($_POST)) { 
    // Obtener datos formulario
    $Nombre =$_POST['nombre'] ?? ''; 
    $Apellido =$_POST['apellido'] ?? ''; 
    $Correo = $_POST['correo'] ?? ''; 
    $Telefono = $_POST['telefono'] ?? ''; 
    $Especialidad = $_POST['especialidad'] ?? ''; 

    // Datos son verdaderos
    if ($Nombre && $Apellido && $Correo && $Telefono && $Especialidad) {
        // Instancias objeto
        $ModeloDocente = new Docente(); 
        // Insertar datos
        $insert = $ModeloDocente->add($Nombre,$Apellido,$Correo,$Telefono,$Especialidad); 
        // Devuelves respuesta a AJAX
        echo $insert; // Devolvera 1 o 0
    }
// Formulario no existe
} else { 
    header('Location:../../Login.php'); 
}
```

Tu funcion quedaria asi:

```
public function add($nombre , $apellido ,$correo ,$telefono ,$especialidad){
    $statement = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO docentes(Nombre , Apellido ,Correo ,Telefono ,Especialidad) VALUES (:nombre , :apellido , :correo, :telefono, :especialidad)");
    $statement->bindParam(':nombre',$nombre);
    $statement->bindParam(':apellido',$apellido);
    $statement->bindParam(':telefono',$correo);
    $statement->bindParam(':correo',$telefono);
    $statement->bindParam(':especialidad',$especialidad);

    if($statement->execute()){
        return 1;
    }else{
        return 0; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda

Comment: @eduardomanjarres de nada amigo, si te ha solucionado el problema, podrías votarla a favor o aceptarla si creas que te soluciono el problema, y así queda cerrada tu pregunta. Suerte con tu proyecto, un saludo.